# How to make a student evaluation using Blackboard?

Tags: teaching, evaluation, course-evaluation

This is my first year to teach classes in computer science as an instructor. I am looking to get student feedback about the course so far. I know that there is a student evaluation at the end of the semester, but i am looking to get the feedback now using the blackboard. Any suggestions to how to create a good evaluation survey on the blackboard? **I am looking to use that student evaluations and put it in my CV incase it was good evaluations**

Comment: Are you referring to the Blackboard, the learning software?

Comment: Is there a survey function or activity? Even a quiz could be used if you work on the questions...

Comment: Did you ask your local learning technologist this question?

Comment: @GoodDeeds +1: Heba Mohsen, can you edit your question to clarify? I read _the blackboard_ to mean a physical board attached to the wall that can be written on with chalk. (Actually, I believe that's the only reading.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how well it works, but under Course Tools you'll find 'Tests, Surveys and Pools'.  The 'survey' option lets you write a course survey.